# Remap with number-limits and not individual values in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, reclassify

I have a rather basic question regarding the reclassification of ImageCollections in GEE. When I want to reclass individual values, I use the `remap` function as follow

```
var my_reclass= function(image) {
  var myreclass = image.remap([10 ,12],[  0,   3], null, 'my reclass');    
};
```

What I would like to do though and I can not find any examples, is to use number limits for my reclassification

e.g.

-1 thru 3 = 5

3.1 thru 8.2 = 1

...

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you need is something like this:

```js
var random = ee.Image.random()

var customRemap = function(image, lowerLimit, upperLimit, newValue) {
  var mask = image.gte(lowerLimit).and(image.lt(upperLimit))
  return image.where(mask, newValue)
}

// values from 0 to 0.5 will be 10, the rest will not change
var remaped = customRemap(random, 0, 0.5, 10) 

Map.addLayer(random)
Map.addLayer(remaped)
```

Comment: Thank you both. The solutions work but it easier for me to understand Rodrigo's one.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this. Values below the first threshold will be 0, from the first to second threshold limit will then be 1, the second to third will be 2 and so on.

```
// make a random image (ranging form 0 - 1 automatically)
var randomImage = ee.Image.random();
// set some thresholds between which you want to remap
var limits = [0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8];
// reclassify
var reclassified = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(ee.List(limits).map(function(limit){
  return randomImage.gt(ee.Number(limit));
})).sum();
```