# Remap adding values to raster in Google Earth Engine

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, reclassify

I'm following [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317305/remap-with-number-limits-and-not-individual-values-in-gee) for a remap I'm trying to do. However, my output ended up adding hundreds of new pixel values. I simply wanted to reclassify specific values. Would anyone be able to explain why my output looks the way it does?[image: raster image] My code is as shown below, where I want to reclassify values 82 to 84 to show as 1. Note: I don't want to reclassify ranges in general, this is just an example of 3 individual values that I'd like to reclassify.

```
var raster = ee.Image(StateClassRaw)

var customRemap = function(image, lowerLimit, upperLimit, newValue) {
  var mask = image.gte(lowerLimit).and(image.lt(upperLimit))
  return image.where(mask, newValue)
}

var remaped = customRemap(raster, 82, 84, 1) 

Map.addLayer(remapped)
```

Comment: Can you please confirm that the original image does not contain the added values you are describing? The code you provided should keep all the values as-is except for 82,83,84, which will have the value of 1.

Comment: I can confirm that the added values I'm describing don't appear in the original image. I produced a frequency table on the original raster and those values aren't present. There are 42 values in the original raster vs 902 in the remapped. @Aaron

Comment: I also see you are calling a variable you have not defined yet when you use `Map.addLayer(remapped)`. Probably a typo, but you may be referencing some other dataset you worked with in another part of the script.